# How can I wait for a command-line program to finish?

Tags: delphi, command-line

I have run program with command-line parameters. How can i wait for it to finish running?

Comment: cant say what question is very clear for me... for CLI `input` comes from `stdin` and `output` goes to `stdout` (or `stderr` in some cases). parameters acting as modifiers for program behaviour

Comment: Please rephrase your question, as the current form is very unclear. What are you waiting for? Console output of the executed program? Windows messages sent by that program?

Comment: Sorry for my bad English ! i found the answer . you can see that in bottom of the page !

Comment: It *that's* the answer, then you didn't ask your question very clearly. I've edited it for you so that it matches what you apparently intended to ask.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is my answer : (Thank you all)

```
uses ShellAPI;

function TForm1.ShellExecute_AndWait(FileName: string; Params: string): bool;
var
  exInfo: TShellExecuteInfo;
  Ph: DWORD;
begin

  FillChar(exInfo, SizeOf(exInfo), 0);
  with exInfo do
  begin
    cbSize := SizeOf(exInfo);
    fMask := SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS or SEE_MASK_FLAG_DDEWAIT;
    Wnd := GetActiveWindow();
    exInfo.lpVerb := 'open';
    exInfo.lpParameters := PChar(Params);
    lpFile := PChar(FileName);
    nShow := SW_SHOWNORMAL;
  end;
  if ShellExecuteEx(@exInfo) then
    Ph := exInfo.hProcess
  else
  begin
    ShowMessage(SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));
    Result := true;
    exit;
  end;
  while WaitForSingleObject(exInfo.hProcess, 50) <> WAIT_OBJECT_0 do
    Application.ProcessMessages;
  CloseHandle(Ph);

  Result := true;

end;
```

Comment: You should use MsgWaitForMultipleObjects() instead of WaitForSingleObject() so you do not call Application.ProcessMessages() unnecessarily.  Doing so too often can degrade your app's performance while your loop is running.

Comment: I'll use it in a thread ! so Application.ProcessMessages; will remove !

Comment: MsgWaitForMultipleObjects really is likely to be the better solution - you'll only have to wait for the thread if you did it that way!

Comment: Working fine in XE3 with Params = ''. But just curious what kind of Params can I pass to that function?

Answer (score 7):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to execute program in command-line and capture its output in your application rather than in console window. To do so, you can read the output using [pipes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365780%28VS.85%29.aspx). Here is an example source code:

[Capture the output from a DOS (command/console) Window](http://delphi.about.com/cs/adptips2001/a/bltip0201_2.htm)

Answer (score 4):

Using [DSiWin32](http://gp.17slon.com/gp/dsiwin32.htm):

```
sl := TStringList.Create;
if DSiExecuteAndCapture('cmd.exe /c dir', sl, 'c:\test', exitCode) = 0 then
  // exec error
else
  // use sl
sl.Free;
```

Comment: @gabr-Hi! I got DSIWin32 v1.70b - Is this a beta version?

Comment: @gabr-And another question. The application freezes while it captures the output. There is a way to show dynamically the captured output.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, getting the command-line parameters, you use

`ParamCount` : returns the number of parameters passed to the program on the command-line.

`ParamStr` : returns a specific parameter, requested by index.
[Running Dephi Applications With Parameters](http://delphi.about.com/od/beginners/a/runwithparams.htm)

Now, if what you meant is reading and writing to the console, you use

`WriteLn` : writes a line of text to the console.

`ReadLn` : reads a line of text from the console as a string.
[Delphi Basics](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=Output)

Answer (score 2):

If what you want is to execute a command-line executable, and get the response that this exe writes to the console, the easiest way could be to call the exe from a batch file and redirect the output to another file using `>`, and then read that file.

For example, if you need to execute the "dir" command and get its output you could have a batch file called `getdir.bat` that contains the following:

```
@echo off
dir c:\users\myuser\*.* > output.txt
```

you could exec that batch file using the API function ShellExecute. You can read about it http://delphi.about.com/od/windowsshellapi/a/executeprogram.htm

Then you can read output file, even using something like a TStringList:

```
var
  output: TStringList;
begin
  output := TStringList.Create();
  output.LoadFromFile('output.txt');
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks from [this](https://tips.delphidabbler.com/tips/17) - Changed & Tested:

```
function ExecAndWait(ExeFileName, CommandLine: string): Boolean;
var
  ExitCode: DWORD;
  ProcessInformation: TProcessInformation;
  StartupInfo: TStartupInfo;
begin
  Result := False;
  FillChar(StartupInfo, SizeOf(TStartupInfo), 0);
  StartupInfo.cb := SizeOf(TStartupInfo);
  // Hide process
  // https://stackoverflow.com/a/26775986/3055142
  StartupInfo.wShowWindow := SW_HIDE;
  StartupInfo.dwFlags := STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
  if CreateProcess(PChar(ExeFileName), PChar(CommandLine), nil, nil, False, 0, nil, nil, StartupInfo, ProcessInformation) then
  begin
    if WAIT_OBJECT_0 = WaitForSingleObject(ProcessInformation.hProcess, INFINITE) then
      if GetExitCodeProcess(ProcessInformation.hProcess, ExitCode) then
        if ExitCode = 0 then
          Result := True
        else
          SetLastError(ExitCode + $2000);

    ExitCode := GetLastError;
    CloseHandle(ProcessInformation.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(ProcessInformation.hThread);
    SetLastError(ExitCode);
  end;
end;
```